# Merging an svn working copy into a git working copy and vise versa?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, smartgit

Circumstances require that I version my own work on a git repo while the "trunk" for the project is on an svn repo, meaning I will regularly need to update my svn working copy and merge its revisions into my git working copy, and vise versa. Is there any easy way to do this in svn and git? I am currently using SmartGit and TortiseSVN as clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `git svn`.  Check the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) for more details, but the basic idea is that you clone the `svn` repo with `git svn clone`, and then keep everything up to date with `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit`.

Comment: Any idea how I would do that in SmartGit? It only gives me the option of cloning either SVN or Git, not git-svn, and I don't see anywhere to enter my git repository when I've pulled the svn repo or vise versa. New question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127997/merging-an-svn-working-copy-into-a-git-working-copy-and-vise-versa/16128010?noredirect=1#16128010). In the case that it does not, I would still be interested in knowing how to merge working copies.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the command line?  I guess in the worst case, you could just use `git` with `SmartGit` and make an intermediate repository to handle the `svn` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository with SmartGit/Hg. Depending on the URL, it will recognize immediately that it's an SVN repository or it will ask you. In this case, select **SVN**. The resulting clone is similar to what you will get when using *git-svn*, however SmartGit's functionality is significantly more powerful:

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/svn-tour.html

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation.html?page=concepts-svn

Comment: Thanks- I went over those again even though I've been over them many times before- but I still don't see how it will let me do what I'm talking about. What it sounds like to me is using SmartGit with an SVN lets you emulate some of the functionality of Git with an SVN repository, but I have not seen anything in the docs explaining how to use it with your Git repository at the same time (which is what I'm trying to do). Can you tell me exactly where it explains how to do something like push or pull from your Git repository after having cloned your SVN repository?

Comment: SmartGit/Hg will give you a fully functional Git repository. Instead of having a usual "Git remote", you will have an "SVN remote". As for Git remotes, you can Push to/Pull from the SVN remote. Also note, that you won't need another Git repository (what I understand you currently have).